# JQuery PHP data attribute doesn't return correct

Tags: php, jquery, attributes

I have a button:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-default approve" title="<?= _('Approve all') ?>" data-authorized="<?php $authorized ?>" id="approveButton" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> Approve all
    </button>
</div>
```

and I'm trying to read the `data-authorized` using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', "button.approve", function (event) {
        var authorized = $(event.currentTarget).data('authorized');
        alert($(event.currentTarget).data('authorized'));
        alert($(this).data('authorized'));
        alert($(this).attr('data-authorized'));
        alert($('#approveButton').data('authorized'));
    });
});
```

I have tried several approaches, but none of them are showing the correct value of the $authorized. I just get an empty alert, no undefined, false or true.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because `data-authorized` is __empty__. And it is empty because you don't `echo` anything.

Comment: `data-authorized="<?php $authorized ?>"`  need to be `data-authorized="<?php echo $authorized ?>"`

Comment: Btw. Instead of `$(event.currentTarget)` you can do just `$(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***`data-authorized` is `empty` since you didn't `echo` anything***

Change

```
data-authorized="<?php $authorized ?>"
```

To

```
data-authorized="<?php echo $authorized; ?>"
```

***And then your code will work (only this much required):-***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', "button.approve", function (event) {
        alert($(this).data('authorized'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it:

```
data-authorized="<?php $authorized ?>"
```

to

```
data-authorized="<?php echo $authorized ?>"
```

and try again